# How to auto update the Qlistwidet based on the text entered in Qlineedit?

Tags: python, filter, pyqt5, qlineedit, qlistwidget

Hi I have a qlistwidget and a qlineedit. What I want to achieve is when I put any texts in qlineedit, my qlistwidget will autopopulate based on the text in qlineedit.

This is the code I have worked so far:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(345, 340)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 256, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.selectall_initial_listwidget = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem('(Select All)')
        self.selectall_initial_listwidget.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        self.listWidget.addItem(self.selectall_initial_listwidget)

        names_list = ['Jessa', 'Aejes', 'Jerome', 'Bajesryn', 'James', 'Junrey']

        self.widget_list = []

        for name in names_list:
            self.widget_item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(name)
            self.widget_item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.widget_list.append(self.widget_item)
            self.listWidget.addItem(self.widget_item)

        self.listWidget.sortItems(QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 30, 251, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Currently this is how it looks.

[image]

What I want to achieve is when I type small letter **'jes'** in lineedit. The qlistwidget will autopopulate with any 'jes' in the list. 'Aejes' 'Bajesryn', and 'Jessa' will auto-show-up in the list without pressing any buttons.

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, yes thats exactly what I want. Not much sure if its 'filter' called thats why i didnt emphasize that much. But yes, filter is what I want. Can you help me on that?Thanks!

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, thanks for recommending others post, however based on the recommendation of the answer in that post, the answer there is by pressing the button and it will filter. What I want is that it will filter automatically without pressing any button as I mentioned in my question. The same behavior in an excel when you filter and type words in the lineedit the below listwidget will automatically update. Really new to this so apprecaite if can you help me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: thank you so much!!!

Comment: Hi eyllane, would just like to follow-up a simple function related to this thread, when i enter backspace key the filter is not functioning (i mean the list widget do not autofilter). I think I missed something basic function. appreciate your expertise help. thank you!

Comment: you may ignore my request. i already solved it. thanks!!